# Monodevelop - Try to install on linux Precise 64 (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to install Monodevelop from http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives.

I'm using a virtual Box VM via Vagrant with an Ubuntu Precise 64 Guest OS

I have done this steps :

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update

echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy-libtiff-compat main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

At this point, all seems OK.
But when I want to install the first package "mono-devel" by typing

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```

I have the following error message

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo apt-get install mono-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-devel : Depends: libgdiplus (>= 2.6.7) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-design4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-messaging4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel-activation4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel-web4.0-cil (>= 3.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil (>= 3.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-serviceprocess4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil (>= 2.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web-webpages-razor2.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web-webpages2.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web4.0-cil (>= 2.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 4.4.1.0-0xamarin1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
vagrant@precise64:~$ lsb_release
No LSB modules are available.
vagrant@precise64:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS \n \l
```

I have also tried doing a "sudo apt-get upgrade" without any success.

I thought that apt could also download and install all package dependencies. Why the libraries files mentioned in the error message can't be loaded ?

How to solve the problem ? Is there a mistake somewhere ?

As SushiHangover advises me in the answer below, I have also tried to install libgdiplus but there is also an error message :

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo apt-get install libgdiplus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgdiplus : Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) but 2.8.0-3ubuntu9.1 is to be installed
              Depends: libtiff5 (> 4.0.0-1~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After manually installed libtiff5 package :

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant$ sudo apt-get install libgdiplus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgdiplus : Depends: libcairo2 (>= 1.4) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libexif12 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libfontconfig1 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxrender1 but it is not going to be installed
 libtiff5 : Depends: libjbig0 (>= 2.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614) but 5.1.1alpha+20110809-3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt-get install libtiff5`? if there are no failed dependencies on it, you can download `libtiff5` manually, install it and try `mono-devel` again... otherwise keep walking down the dependancies to find the package that is causing the issue on your system...

Comment: No I didn't. After doing it I have again en error message : vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo apt-get install libtiff5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libtiff5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libtiff5' has no installation candidate

Comment: `libtiff5` is available via ubuntu xenial @  http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libtiff5 . I would  download the amd64 package manually, install it and try mono-devel again

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgdiplus
```

If it results in:

```
~~~
libgdiplus : Depends: libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1) but it is not installable
~~~
```

Then you need to get the older libjpeg62 package:

```
wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg6b/libjpeg62_6b2-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --install --recursive --auto-deconfigure libjpeg62_6b2-2_amd64.deb
```

Now you can:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

Comment: http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg6b/libjpeg62_6b2-2_amd64.deb <-- http 404 bro

Comment: 7year old link "bro", try digging a little: http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg6b/

Answer (score 0):

New mono versions need libtiff5 package version >=4.0, and Ubuntu 12.x hasn't this package. 
But this package version depends on other new packages or existing packages with newer versions...

There is a working solution (on amd64 platform):

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-freefont/fonts-freefont-ttf_20120503-4_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/fonts-freefont/ttf-freefont_20120503-4_all.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig/fontconfig-config_2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2_all.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fontconfig/libfontconfig1_2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/j/jbigkit/libjbig0_2.1-3.1_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xz-utils/liblzma5_5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tiff/libtiff5_4.0.6-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg --install --recursive --auto-deconfigure fonts-freefont-ttf_20120503-4_all.deb
sudo dpkg --install --recursive --auto-deconfigure ttf-freefont_20120503-4_all.deb
sudo dpkg --install --recursive --auto-deconfigure fontconfig-config_2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg --install --recursive --auto-deconfigure libfontconfig1_2.11.0-0ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --install --recursive --auto-deconfigure libjbig0_2.1-3.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --install --recursive --auto-deconfigure liblzma5_5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --install --recursive --auto-deconfigure libtiff5_4.0.6-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```